# Unity how to randomize models?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm developing a Unity game. I have 3 different models, what I'm trying to do is, after few seconds of the game, I want one of these models appears on the screen randomly each time the game is started. How can I do that? please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class RandomObjectSpawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private float waitTime;    // The time You want to wait before Instantiating an object

    [SerializeField]
    private List<GameObject> models;   // Your models Add them through the inspector

    private GameObject selectedModel; 

    private float timer; 

    void Start()
    {
        timer = 0f;

        int randomizedIndex = Random.Range(0, models.Count);
        selectedModel = models[randomizedIndex];
    }

    
    void Update()
    {

        timer += Time.deltaTime;

        if(timer >= waitTime)
        {
            Instantiate(selectedModel);  // Instantiate our model
            
        }
    }
 }
```

### Notes

You have to assign your models , WaitTime through the inspector .

You need to set the waitTime to a value bigger than 0 .

You can modify the Position an object spawns at , by default it will spawn in the position of the object with this script .

or You can use a spawnPosition of your choice

```
Instantiate(selectedModel,spawnPosition,Quaternion.identity);
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a field to store the models

```
public List<GameObject> myModels;
```

then at start you randomize one

```
private void Start()
{
   var randomizedIndex = Random.Range(0, myModels.Count);
   var selectedModel = myModels[randomizedIndex];
   // instantiate the selected model
}
```